# Replace row values in Panda columns

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe column which is a date and I would like to replace it like this:

Current DataFrame:

```
data = {'date': ['1/1/2022', '1/2/2022,1/3/2022]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Target DataFrame:

```
data = {'date': ['qid:0', 'qid:1','qid:2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Is the goal to replace each element with a string starting with `qid:` followed by the number of days since `1/1/2022`? What's the intent, here?

Comment: Apologies, didn't explain that well. It is actually simpler than that, the intent is just to assign a unique integer following the qid:. Increasing integers might be best, so Jan 1st is 1, and the Jan 2nd is 2 and so on (no repeating integers though, it should be unique).

Comment: Might be easiest maybe to create a mapping and then replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) to encode the object as an enumerated type

```py
df['qid'] = (pd.Series(pd.factorize(pd.to_datetime(df['date']), sort=True)[0])
             .astype(str).radd('qid:'))
```

```
print(df)

       date    qid
0  1/1/2022  qid:0
1  1/2/2022  qid:1
2  1/3/2022  qid:2
```

Comment: Is there a way of converting it back to the original after this?

Comment: It was anwered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76047580/replace-row-values-in-panda-columns-temporarily-and-convert-back. Thank you again!!