# Replace row values in Panda columns temporarily and convert back

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column which is a date and I would like to replace it with ordered integers like this and then back (not one way but roundtrip)

Current DataFrame:

```
data = {'date': ['1/1/2022', '1/2/2022,1/3/2022]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Target DataFrame:

```
data = {'qid': ['0', '1','2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75972956/replace-row-values-in-panda-columns) I asked the one way question, and got this answer which works one way (slightly modified):

```
df['qid'] = (pd.Series(pd.factorize(pd.to_datetime(df['date']), sort=True)[0]))
```

Is there a way, of getting it back to the dates after this transformation?

Comment: I have _so_ many questions. You want to encode dates as integers. Why?

Comment: Very good question. It is a long story, I am using a PyTorch model, that requires a specific type of input, namely various lists that are grouped by query IDs. My dataset doesn't quite fit this mold, so my workaround is to pretend that my dates are query IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`factorize` returns a tuple whose second item is the unique values which you can use to convert the codes back to the original values:

```
df['gid'], uniques = pd.factorize(df['date'])

uniques[df['gid']]
```

Output:

```
Index(['1/1/2022', '1/2/2022', '1/3/2022'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Fair, that does seem to be the question, sorry

Comment: My mind is blown, so simply. Thank you!!!!